# saving highscore to other class

Tags: android, class, save, settext

my problem is i dont know how to  save a highscore score to my highscore.class

the scenario or flow of my game is like this.

after the user finishes the quiz game the finish.class will  pop up and have a button that if you press that buttong it will autommatically set text a score to my highscore.class

example is:
finish.class
save highscore(button)-user clicks

highscore.class
set text(textview)-that will display automatically if the user clicks the save highscore button from finish.class

HIGH SCORE
10/10(score of the user)

hope you get my explanation :). really appreciate your answer to my question. newbie here :) can you show me a sample or source code for this

just to make it simple. a button that will set text to another .class

finish.class

```
public class finishextends Activity {
Button save highscore;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.timesup);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
save highscore= (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_highscore);
save highscore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override   
       public void onClick(View v) {


    }
});
}
```

}

highscore.class just my back button

public class HighScore extends Activity {

```
Button back;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.highscore);
    back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_backk);
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override   
       public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Back",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainMenu.class);
            startActivity(intent);
    }
 });    
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared preference to save high score like then you can pass current score with intents:

on saveHighScore onClick:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Finish.this);
if (score > preferences.getInt("score", 0)) {
     preferences.edit().putInt("score", score).commit();
}
Intent showHighScore = new Intent(Finish.this, HighScoreActivity.class);
showHighScore.putExtra("current_score", score);
startActivity(showHIghScore);
```

then onCreate of your HighScoreActivity

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
int currentScore = getIntent().getIntExtra("current_score", 0);
highScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.highscore);
highScore.setText(currentScore + " / " + preferences.getInt("score", 0));
```

Comment: how can i make it like every i click the button the result will be 8/10 eight out of ten

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you actually want to do. But my suggestion is here.

After finishing the game, you can simply save the score of this user in the SQLite database and use it anywhere you want to display it.

Secondly, as per your code. You can pass the score in a intent to the other activity. And when that activity starts you can get that score from the intent.

```
public class finishextends Activity {
Button highscore;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.timesup);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
highscore= (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_highscore);
highscore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override   
       public void onClick(View v) {
        //Pass your score to other activity through Android's intent.
       Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    HighScore.class);
       //THis highestScore variable will actually hold the score you get in this activity.
       intent.putExtra("score", highestScore);
       startActivity(intent);
    }
});
}
}
```

Now get this data in your HighScore.java activity class.

```
 public class HighScore extends Activity {

Button back;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.highscore);

    int highestScore = -1;
//Now use this score variable to set anywhere.
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras != null) {
        highestScore = extras.getString("score");
        }


    back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_backk);
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override   
       public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Back",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
 });    
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
}
```

Comment: can i use that in tomcat?

Comment: if (extras != null) {
      highestScore = extras.getString("score");-i have an error in this line
         }

Comment: In your case the value you pass is Integer type so use:



   highestScore = extras.getInt("score");

Comment: Instead use: extras.getDouble("score");

THis will work for Integer or Double both types.

Comment: how can i set text a score?

Comment: intent.putExtra("score", highestScore);// i have an error on this one. should i implement int highestScore; ?

Comment: Create a variable highestScore on int type and put your score in this variable and pass it through intent.

Comment: how can i have a set text that if we click the button highscore there will be e textview showing my score on my highscore.class

Comment: highestScore = extras.getInt("score");

Set this score to a TextView in your  HighScore class. 

Please accept my answer if it is useful.

Comment: Set it on a TextView in the activity you want to show it.

It would work. 

Nothing can be said without looking at your code, and without knowing where you actually want to show it and how are you displaying it?